# how to put a variable that i declare inside AssetImage

Tags: flutter, dart

For example, i getting a list of restaurant from database and i only want the url of the image to put into the AssetImage but it cant work. I try to use Image.asset but the Imageprovider cannot put Image.asset.

final restaurantlist = _restaurant.restaurant[index];

AssetImage(restaurantlist.imageurl); <--- error
Image.asset(restuarantlist.imagerurl); <--- working fine

any idea why AssetImage cant work?

Answer (score 1):

**[Image](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html)** has several constructors.

> **Image**, for obtaining an image from an ***ImageProvider***.
>
> **Image.asset**, for obtaining **an image from an AssetBundle using a
>   key**.
>
> **Image.network**, for obtaining an **image from a URL**.
>
> Image.file, for obtaining an image from a File.
>
> Image.memory, for obtaining an image from a Uint8List.

---

---

**[AssetImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/AssetImage-class.html)** class

> **fetches** an image from an AssetBundle,

and Inherits

**[ImageProvider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html)** < AssetBundleImageKey >

> Identifies an image **without committing to the precise final asset**.

---

**TL;DR**

When downloading images use:

```
Image.network(imgUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

In flutter, you can show images with `Image` Widget it takes a property called `image` which takes any class which extends `ImageProvider` class which is used to resolve the image you want Since the `AssetImage` extends `ImageProvider` it will just resolve your image assets, you will need to provide it to an `Image` Widget like so:

```
Image(image: AssetImage(restaurantlist.imageurl));
```

And the `Image.asset` is just a shorthand for the above code.

Answer (score 0):

instead of AssetImage use FileImage

```
       DecorationImage(
            image: FileImage("your image url") as ImageProvider,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
```

this is my example to have dynamic background for your app
you cans just use FileImage instead of AssetImage